# Security aspects: set a password to recovery mode, encrypt a directory

Tags: security, password

I wish to give more security to my r-pi which will be left in a public place.
Particularly, I would like know how to

- set a password to "revovery mode"
- encrypt a specific folder in which there is my code and I must to execute this code from a crontab
- any other idea
  Thanks.

Comment: While you may find a way to password protect single-user mode (which will require local access to use), you will not be able to protect against someone inserting their own SD card and/or stealing yours with software alone.

Comment: Even using something like encfs will still require that the root user has access to the decryption key to run anything in it with crontab. So, the comment above is completely valid and I do not think that there is any possibility of software security without physical security of the device.

Comment: Is there a way to encrypt a specific folder such as /home/pi/my_code_dir ?